# How to get text value from a "display:none;" css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, text, display

I am beginner with html and javascript, i have a example that i need to hide some text and that text will not take any place on my web. So, I set it's CSS  to display:none. But i want get some text inside it. Can any one tell me how to get it? or some ways to do it. 
This is my example:

```
<td class="HiddentText" style="display:none;">My Hidden Text</td>
```

i was tried:

```
$('.HiddentText').val() 
$('.HiddentText').text()
```

but i got nothing from it.

Comment: Works for me: http://jsbin.com/urihur/1/edit

Comment: The second try should work. `.val()` is for inputs, not text elements.

Comment: Is your jQuery wrapped in a `$(document).ready(function(){/* your code here */});`?

Comment: How many elements do you have in your page with HiddentText class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a JSFiddle for this problem and I only got it working when I added the required `<table>` and `<tr>` statements around the `<td>` element:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="HiddentText" style="display: none;">My Hidden Text</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Then you can do:

```
$(document).ready(function() {    
    alert($('.HiddentText').html());
});
```

See my working JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kgjux/

And my non-working JSFiddle (which does not have the `<table>` and `<tr>` elements): http://jsfiddle.net/44Unf/

Answer (score 1):

You actually had the right answer: `.text()` method.

1. `.val()` will give you value of an element that actually has a value (like input, textarea)
2. `.html()` is to get whatever HTML code is inside the element
3. `.text()` will give you text (visible or not visible to user) inside the element, but with no html formatting, just text.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.HiddentText').html()); // for class
$('#HiddentText').html()); // for id
```

value from elements like paragraph, div, td, span etc are taken through .html() in jquery or .innerHTML() in plain javascript

Answer (score -3):

You need add ';' at the end of function.
$('.HiddentText').val(); means return value="something"